# C++ + RethinkDb = is it possible?

Tags: c++, driver, rethinkdb

I know that there is no official `RethinkDB` driver for `C++` (what is really strange for such a mainstream language). But I also know that there is an unofficial [driver](https://github.com/AtnNn/librethinkdbxx), which, however does not work (at least for me). So, this is what I tried:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/AtnNn/librethinkdbxx
$ cd librethinkdbxx
$ make test
```

As a result of what the author suggests to do, I get this error message `ImportError: no module named yaml`. Even though `yaml` is installed. So, I can not move even one step further, since tests fail.

Comment: That error is coming from Python. You might have `yaml` installed, but do you have [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/)?

Comment: As, I have said, I have it. I installed it like `$ sudo pip install pyyaml`

Comment: `yaml` is called from [link](https://github.com/AtnNn/librethinkdbxx/blob/master/test/yaml_to_cxx.py), are you sure that `yaml` is in your python module path? perhaps the makefile is calling the wrong version of python

Comment: makefile calls `python3`, are you sure you have installed the right version of yaml?

Comment: I replaced python3 with python2.7 in make file, but now get other error message like `SyntaxError: invalid syntax ^ print("While translating: " + python, file=stdr)`. So, I guess all these infinite errors mean that C++ and RethinkDB will hardly work together.

Comment: @Jacobian: no, all those errors mean that Python 3 and Python 2 are not the same thing. The language changed from 2 to 3. If the Makefile needs Python 3, then it needs to be installed.

Comment: @  dlavila ,  did you have a chance to do `$ make test ` yourself?

Comment: no, but @Cornstalks is right, e.g `print(... , ...)` is not a valid call in python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver can be built and installed without running the tests. To build the driver, simply run `make`, as described in the README. Python is not required for building and using the driver.

To install it, run `make install` with an optional `prefix=` argument.

`make test` runs the test suite, which requires Python 3, the Python YAML module and maybe other dependencies. The lack of those dependencies seems to be the source of your errors.

You can confirm that these dependencies are installed if this command reports no errors: `python3 -c 'import yaml'`. If the `yaml` module is missing, you may have to run `pip3 install yaml`.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Now, I see, it works great. Actually, what I had to do is to edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` (I added a line pointing to the folder with librethinkdb++.so), then I ran `$ ldconfig` and it all started to work! PS. I did it in order to make a shared module for Python.